# Connecting Excel to a Azure Devops Query

Tags: azure-devops

I can not see my queries using Excel Team plugin. I get an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2fGr.png)

TF8001:An error occurred while accessing the work item database. Contact the administrator

Comment: Please provide more context on how the connection is setup.

Comment: I use this plugin https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other-family Azure DevOps Office® Integration 2019 I can connect to Azure Devops see the list of projects, but when I click on a project I get the error I specified in my previous message.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the administrator account to check these:

**First**, please [check whether the current query allows your account to access it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/set-query-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-permissions-on-a-shared-query).

click on the **Shared query**-->**Security**

[image]

Make sure that the related options are allowed.

**Second**, make sure that [your account has access to the current work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path).

**Project Settings**--> **Project configuration**

[image]

**Finally** if you execute the query to tfs work item database, you should contact your Administrator to add permission for your account.